Explicit `this: <type>` in TypeScript functions
I'm reading Declaring this in a Function from the TypeScript Handbook, and I'm confused by this example:

... but there are a lot of cases where you need more control over what
object this represents. The JavaScript specification states that you
cannot have a parameter called this, and so TypeScript uses that
syntax space to let you declare the type for this in the function
body.
This pattern is common with callback-style APIs, where another object
typically controls when your function is called.
interface DB {
  filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean): User[];
}
 
const db = getDB();
const admins = db.filterUsers(function (this: User) {
  return this.admin;
});


I didn't fully get this paragraph message, in particular how filterUsers method should be implemented so that explicit this: User would work, so I decided to bring this example to a working state:
type User = {
  id: number;
  admin: boolean;
}

interface DB {
  filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean): User[];
}

const users: User[] = [
    { id: 1, admin: true },
    { id: 2, admin: false },
  ];

const db:DB = {
  filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean) {
    return users.filter(filter);
  }
};


const admins = db.filterUsers(function (this: User) {
  return this.admin;
});

console.log(admins);

Obviously this example won't work, although the compiler doesn't complain. It's even more clear from the resulting JavaScript - this will not be User instance inside function (this: User) { return this.admin; } :
"use strict";
const users = [
    { id: 1, admin: true },
    { id: 2, admin: false },
];
const db = {
    filterUsers(filter) {
        return users.filter(filter);
    }
};
const admins = db.filterUsers(function () {
    return this.admin;
});
console.log(admins);

So, what would be the correct implementation filterUsers so that the idea of explicit this: User would work and be useful?

"in particular how filterUsers method should be implemented so that explicit this: User would work," the function needs to be called with a User context. Likely via .apply()/.call()/.bind().

You're not quite asking this, so I guess it's just an aside, but the reason why your failed attempt doesn't have a TS error is the lack of a --strictThis as requested in ms/TS#7968. TS will always let you pass a this-param function where a this-less one is expected, as you see in your code and as minimally demonstrated in this playground link. I'm not sure how to fold this information into your post.

I would recommend the filter function that takes a User object as an argument instead of relying on this:
type User = {
  id: number;
  admin: boolean;
}

interface DB {
  filterUsers(filter: (user: User) => boolean): User[];
}

const users: User[] = [
  { id: 1, admin: true },
  { id: 2, admin: false },
];

const db: DB = {
  filterUsers(filter: (user: User) => boolean) {
    return users.filter(filter);
  }
};

const admins = db.filterUsers((user: User) => {
  return user.admin;
});

console.log(admins);

If you want to try to set the param name to be this, You could also use filter.call(user) inside the filterUsers method, or explicitly bind the object like @rozsazoltan did.
This ensures that this inside the filter function refers to the current user object.
type User = {
  id: number;
  admin: boolean;
}

interface DB {
  filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean): User[];
}

const users: User[] = [
  { id: 1, admin: true },
  { id: 2, admin: false },
];

const db: DB = {
  filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean) {
    return users.filter(user => filter.call(user));
  }
};

const admins = db.filterUsers(function (this: User) {
  return this.admin;
});

console.log(admins);


So, in this example from the book, there is no practical convenience in using explicit this, since it would be clearer to write it in the usual way? function (user: User) { return user.admin; }

@Serg the answer has been updated, I just noticed you want to use this as the param name, which I don't think there is any practical convenience.

@Serg this is my personal opinion, i would always recommend using user:User instead of this:User to avoid any confusion.

My fault was that I was trying to see in their example that an explicit this helps to avoid some kind of error or gives some convenience in writing code. But that example from the book turns out to be far-fetched.

@Serg Update the answer to include both, I still prefer to pass the user object for clarity and simplicity :)

I think you've made a typo because both examples are identical now. But I absolutely agree - using this: User only unnecessarily complicates the code in this context.

@Serg Yes, my mistake. The answer has been updated, thanks!

By using bind, you can ensure that this is indeed the correct User instance during the execution of the filter function.
type User = {
  id: number;
  admin: boolean;
}

interface DB {
  filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean): User[];
}

const users: User[] = [
  { id: 1, admin: true },
  { id: 2, admin: false },
];

const db: DB = {
  filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean) {
    // need to manually bind the `this` context to each user
    return users.filter(user => filter.bind(user)());
  }
};

const admins = db.filterUsers(function (this: User) {
  return this.admin;
});

console.log(admins);


It might look like you have no control over the value of this because its value is set automatically, but that is actually not the case.
Every function has the method .bind, which returns a new function with this bound to a value. The function has exactly the same behavior as the one you called .bind on, only that this was set by you. No matter how or when that function is called, this will always refer to the passed value.
Source: How to access the correct this inside a callback
Felix Kling

